# Ordering Channel Entries results based on Grid content?

Tags: channel-entries, grid, orderby

Is it possible to order `{exp:channel:entries}` results based on the content of a Grid field? In my case, I want to order a list of conference sessions by start time.

This is the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag I'm using:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="sessions" orderby="{session_time}{session_time:start}{/session_time}"}
```

The [Channel Entries](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) entry in the ExpressionEngine documentation doesn't state Grid fields aren't supported.

Comment: How would you order entries by Grid rows if there can be multiple rows per entry?

Comment: That's a fair point... this is the first time I've ever needed to order by grid contents and that particular grid is limited to just a single row. Went with another solution to the problem so, at this point, it's purely theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only order entries by the literal contents of the fieldtype's column in the `exp_channel_data` table. So you can order by `session_time` (if you set that Grid field to be searchable - otherwise the column will not hold any data) - but you will be ordering by the concatenated contents of all columns and rows in that entry's `session_time` field.

You cannot specify a specific column in a Grid field to order by though.